# Python random Circle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How to draw  circles with random radius,colors and positions?  How to declare circle? I've got already functions to make  colors and X Y positions random bur I do not know how to draw a circle

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of many, many ways.

```
import turtle

geoff = turtle.Turtle()

geoff.pencolor(my_color)
geoff.setpos(my_x, my_y)
geoff.circle(my_radius)
```

Where `my_x`, `my_y`, `my_radius` and `my_color` are all predetermined random values, but you said that you could already get those.

Comment: Thank you, thath's what I wanted to get